# External hard drive wont boot? 16.04

Tags: boot, 16.04, hard-drive

I set up an external hard drive to boot using this videos instructions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gsAzRGMimgQ

When I try to boot to the hard drive on my old computer it will start up and I will see the startup screen and it will go black as if it were about to boot, but instead to just restarts and does the same thing again and again. I tried another computer and it simply booted to a black screen. Both computers recognize my hard drive as a bootable device but both fail to boot properly. What do I do?

Comment: Could you give step-by-step summary rather than a video? It makes it easier for us to see the problem faster.

Comment: Sure, I used a live usb flash drive and went through the steps to install ubuntu. Made a 7gb swap partition and made the rest of the drive ext4. Finished the installation and restarted. The entire disk was unallocated prior to this.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? If UEFI http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu You also can use gpt for BIOS booting, but then need a 1 or 2MB unformatted partition with a bios_grub flag.

Answer (score 0):

Make a USB *installation* disk the usual way. Then connect both it and your external disk to one computer. Boot the *install* disk and install to the other disk.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really knowledgeable in ubuntu but how is this different than what I did? I used the install option on the live usb and installed to my external drive.

Comment: Okay then leave both install and external drives in there and choose to boot from the external drive

Comment: It still just restarts over and over without booting anything

Comment: can you boot the internal disk

Comment: Yes I can boot to windows on my internal drive

Comment: please boot from the install disk